# Rails Mailer issue with sending attchemnt over mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am migrating an application from Rails 2.3 to Rails 3.1, the emails are not working, when i send an email with attachment i see a plain/text email with the encoded pdf content in the email instead of as an attachment.

here is the command i used to send email

```
ret = UserMailer.return_forms(@customer[:email], @store, id, @customer[:document]).deliver
```

here is the definition of returns_form, the return_forms is a method in `UserMailer` class `(class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base)`

```
  def return_forms(email, store, order, pdf_document_path)
    load_smtp_settings("noreply")
    @recipients = email
    @subject    = "#{business_name}: Return forms"
    @body       = "Please follow the instructions within the forms to return your merchandise. Thank You."
    attachments['free_book.pdf'] = {mime_type: 'application/pdf',content:  File.read(pdf_document_path) }
    @from       = email
    @date    = Time.zone.now
    @headers    = {}
  end
```

I see the content as

```
--
Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 16:16:26 +0530
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <55c881028af96_48d43fe94782e9a0658aa@amol-desktop.mail>

Please follow the instructions within the forms to return your merchandise. Thank You.

--
Date: Mon, 10 Aug 2015 16:16:26 +0530
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/pdf;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=free_book.pdf
Content-ID: <55c88102872ba_48d43fe94782e9a0657a0@amol-desktop.mail>

JVBERi0xLjQKJcfsj6IKNyAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggOCAwIFIvRmlsdGVy
IC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZT4+CnN0cmVhbQp4nH1W227bOBB991cM0AWqABZLUvc8
bTZNivTiuLUX2GKzD6xE22pk0aWktOnX75CSbUW+xEhkDufMGc4cjvIDKGFA
zad7puvRmy8JLKuRtYJejnyfghd5MQRBSIGjTY4W1srDkB+xeh4HHocQ92yM
clxzr7NFLD6w7fx6WOtn4gWhD2ewjEfeaZIeuHW0GUYxg3Nwn/rhGaI+vnVt
8wzhHN4PqX+GqQ+3njbTxIez8DhOzhD14dZzUM+j8MD3zxH14K3nIOZReEjp
```

Comment: Why would anyone migrate from Rails 2 to Rails 3 now when Rails 3 is no longer supported? Anyway, have you tried attachments['free_book.pdf'] =  File.read(pdf_document_path)?

Comment: I am working on a incremental upgrade. Yes i have tried it and it does not work

Comment: I see. And I assume that you have moved everything to the mailers folder? I have done similar migrations several times, and from what I see in your question all looks good to me. Can you show your mail(...) command? It would be event easier if you could post your whole mailer method and corresponding mailer view, and whatever can come into the picture in between.

Comment: sure, thanks i have modified my question with additional information, can you please take a look at it

Comment: Where is you call for mail() at the end of return_forms? Such as mail(:from => your_from, :to => your_to, :subject => your_subject). I guess it is the problem.

Comment: I think .deliver does it rite? it used to work in rails 2.3

Comment: Mailers were introduced in Rails 3 (it is a huge difference). Before you were calling deiver_..., and Rails was calling something like "mail" method for you. In Rails 3, you have to generate the email by calling mail(), and then just call deliver (with .deliver) on it. Rails 3 way looks more logical to me.

Comment: so you mean, the .deliver also needs to be there and i need to explicitly call mail method?

Comment: yes, I think so (and I am looking in what I have done about my migrations in the past that included attachments too). Just try adding that mail call.

Comment: I added that, i see the headers in the console log look fine, but now the mail is not getting delivered

Comment: Are you still calling .deliver? We can switch to chat and look into it further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86603/discussion-between-opensource-ios-and-gen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return_forms call should have a call for mail() method at the end. Something like:

```
mail(:from => your_from, :to => your_to, :subject => your_subject, :body => your_body)
```

It is also a good idea to enable mailer errors in your development.rb to see if any errors appear:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```